# sending query over c++

Tags: c++, sql

I have the following data stored in string ;

```
string name = "gokera atoram"
```

And, I want send this using sql command in c++

```
mysql_query ( ... , ? ) ;
```

What should I write to the place marked with '?' ?

command :

```
insert into Names values ( name );
```

EDIT:

further information, I take data from standart input

cin >> name 
   mysql_query ( ..., ? )

if I write like "insert ... ( name ) ", name will be treated as string not as variable name .

Comment: @Sayem, look "Insert into test_tbl(fid, fvarchar20) values (1, 'Some string (1)')");,  in " ", there is a string, not variable name.

Comment: @user1147125: Can't you use string concatenation to concatenate your string variable's value with this query string?

Comment: You can use `ostringstream` to format the query. If you don't have any documentation for `ostringstream` you can use Google to search for it.

Comment: @Benoit, yeah, you got me, it's a homework. Instructor said who solve  this question takes 1000 grade and earn 100000$. This type question is always asked in cs course because it is too complicated ... Are you kidding me ? Have you ever seen  as this type homework before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-query.html).
It says:

> **int mysql_query(MYSQL *mysql, const char *stmt_str)**
>
> **Description**
>
> Executes the SQL statement pointed to by the null-terminated string
>   **stmt_str**. Normally, the string must consist of a single SQL statement
>   and you should not add a terminating semicolon (“;”) or \g to the
>   statement. If multiple-statement execution has been enabled, the
>   string can contain several statements separated by semicolons.

I guess [this example](http://www.cpp-home.com/tutorials/202_1.htm) could be helpful

Comment: please delete your answer so that I can erase my question. I don't understand why they vote down. I want erase my question.

Comment: Why should i delete my answer? dont you like it? you dont have to delete your question only because someone downvotes it, if someone has a problem with it he would write you a comment, otherwise its his problem not urs, you can hardly write anything on SOverflow without getting downvoted. just dont care for downvotes without comments about the reason for it.